# .NET Server Sent Events with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement [SSE (Server Sent Events)](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) model with client an IHM in HTML5/JS and server side C#. I'm using a [COTS](http://joseoncode.com/2011/06/17/event-driven-http-server-in-c-with-rx-and-httplistener/) that implements a event driven http server with Reactive Extensions in .NET.

**Client SIDE**

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:4444");
source.onmessage = function(event) 
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

1.The browser tolds me "Cross-Origin Request" has been refused. I'm on the same domain, is it normal?

2.Is it possible to adapt this http server to do SSE? If this is not possible, do you know some .NET libs (no copyleft) implementing SSE server side?

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Oups, there is a part missing in this copy/pasted text ! I don't use ASP.NET/PHP or something else for server side. i'm currently using HttpListener (Http socket) in C#

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If SSE is possible in HttpListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The cross-origin can be fixed by adding "Origin:*" tot the headers. This can be done in different places depending on your architecture. With MVC it can be set in the global.asax. When using owin auth you can set it where you configure the authentication with this line: config.EnableCors(); I'm sure there is a lot to find when googling 'cross-origin'.
2. I'm not familiar with SSE. But if it is not working out for you you can check out SignalR.(http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client)
   I found it very easy to implement when i was building a website with chat functionality.

Comment: Sure, i'm not using ASP.NET or something else but is it normal that he considers i'm in cross domain mode ? This is a localhost request. Thanks for your answer ! I added a comment in my first but for your second part.I added this to my header part, it works now.

Comment: I think it considers 127.0.0.1 a different domain than 127.0.0.1:4444. Cross domain is when the calling IP + port is different than the receiving IP  + port